# Time taken to fill up the bucket

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

An empty bucket has a pipe in it. Fluid enters at x l/second. It exits xl/second for each y l in bucket. How long will it take to fill bucket with z l of fluid?

Comment: This is not precalculus. This is a differential equations problem.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks. My bad. I altered the tags.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a first order differential equation. If the amount of water in time $t$ is $g(t)$, then the rate of filling the tank is $(1-\frac{g(t)}{100})\times t$ gallons per second. so you can write the rate of change as $\frac{dg}{dt}=(1-\frac{g(t)}{100}) t$. now we need the initial condition to solve this problem which is $g(0)=0$. to solve this you can use this simple trick :
$$\frac{dg}{1-\frac{g(t)}{100}} = tdt \Rightarrow -100 \ln (1-\frac{g}{100}) = t^2 +Const.$$
the $Const.$ term is calculated from initial condition $g(0)=0$ which gives $Const. = 0$.
so $g(t) = 100\times(1-e^{\frac{-t^2}{100}}) \quad gallons.$
you still need to solve for $g(t) = 50$ to get your desired time.

Comment: Hey, I don't think this is correct. By putting g(t) = 50 , I am getting t as 8.3 , which is clearly not true.